# swift: show animation after returning in ViewController

Tags: ios, swift

I have first `ViewController` and second `ViewController`. When I return to first `ViewController` from second `ViewController` after that I want to show buttons in first `ViewController`.

To returning I use this code:

```
self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

And this code to show buttons in first `ViewController`

```
@IBOutlet weak var infoButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButton: UIButton!

@IBOutlet weak var infoButtonTopConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButtonBottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var infoButtonHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var nextButtonHeightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(true)

    showButtonAnimation()
    //animaton()
}

func showButtonAnimation() {

    self.infoButtonTopConstraint.constant += self.infoButtonHeightConstraint.constant
    self.nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= self.nextButtonHeightConstraint.constant

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                   options: [], animations: {
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
}
```

But buttons not showing when I return from second `ViewController`.

Comment: Show the code where you added the buttons to the viewController.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this

```
func showButtonAnimation() {
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                       options: [], animations: {
        self.infoButtonTopConstraint.constant += self.infoButtonHeightConstraint.constant
        self.nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= self.nextButtonHeightConstraint.constant
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
}
```

**EDIT 1**

`viewWillAppear` not getting called reason : you are presenting 2nd `viewController` as `overCurrentContext` `modalPresentationStyle`.

Just replace `overCurrentContext` with `fullScreen` and it works.

Comment: @111, can you please update your question with screen? Also check `self.infoButtonHeightConstraint.constant` returns 0 or other value.

Comment: @111, Temporary add static value for `self.infoButtonTopConstraint.constant += 100
        self.nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= 100` and check

Comment: When I start my app buttons appears. But without animation. When I returning from other controllers buttons not appears.

Comment: @111 put breakpoint at above 2 lines and check  `self.infoButtonHeightConstraint.constant` returns what value.

Comment: Should I put the cursor on `self.**infoButtonHeightConstraint**.constant`? I do not get anything when I put on **infoButtonHeightConstraint**.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177058/discussion-between-kuldeep-and-111).

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call `viewWillAppear` keep in mind that view where not loaded in main view so animation will not work proper. You should use a `viewDidAppear`.

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        showButtonAnimation()
    }
```

And in your animation method update as below because you change constraint value inside animation block that in need to out of it.

```
func showButtonAnimation() {
    self.infoButtonTopConstraint.constant += self.infoButtonHeightConstraint.constant
    self.nextButtonBottomConstraint.constant -= self.nextButtonHeightConstraint.constant
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, delay: 0.0,
                       options: [], animations: {

        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()

    })
}
```

Comment: It is works when I start app. But not when returning from second controller.

Comment: Please try with static value assign to constraint. like 50 or whatever

Comment: did you check with break point? is viewDidAppear method call?

Comment: viewDidAppear not call after returning from second controller.

Comment: :D then how your animation work...just show your code where you return from.

Comment: I use modalPresentationStyle = .overCurrentContext to go to next controller.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your code and it is working for the first time, but the problem might be every time the constant value of the button constraint are increased.

so they might be hiding behind your main view.

Solution:- you can take flag and change its value when animation is completed.

Now when you come back from the second controller then you have to check in the viewWillAppear that if the buttons are visible or not, if they are visible then you do not have to call the ***showButtonAnimation*** method.

You can see where the buttons are in current screen with clicking on

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwpn1.png]

button to see the UI hierarchy.

Hope this will solve your issue.

Answer (score -1):

You can add a delegate in your `second viewController`. like:

```
protocol SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func vcDismissed()
}

Class SecondViewController : UIViewController {
    weak var delegate: SecondViewControllerDelegate

    .....
    //Where you are dismissing your viewController, call the delegate method in completion. 

    func someMethod() {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: {
            self.delegate.vcDismissed()            
        })
    }
}
```

Now in your `FirstViewController`, conform the protocol and implement the method like below:

```
extension FirstViewController: SecondViewControllerDelegate {
    func vcDismissed() {
        //Here call your showButton method
        self.showButton()
    }
}
```

And do not forget to set the delegate when your are creating the instance of your `secondViewController` where you are presenting it. like

```
objSecondViewController.delegate = self
```

Hope this helps. for any query feel free to leave a comment.

Comment: Where you are calling `self.dismiss`, instead of passing nil to completion call your `showButton` method.

Comment: I call `self.dismiss `  and `showButton ` in other controllers.

Comment: Edited the answer, please have a look.